# Android viewpager fragment lifecyle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, broadcastreceiver

I have a Document `fragment` which is inside `viewpager` and i use same Document fragment's instance in another part of application. My problem is that, in fragment i am registering a broadcast receiver, normally i am unregistering it `onPause` method in fragment. But fragments `onPause` method is not called when i switch another. So next fragment of `viewpager` i use new instance of Document fragment and i am creating new instance of receiver also. But `onReceive` method receiver calls viewpager's document `fragment` method. So when look at logcat i can see that i can not unregister receiver. How can i unregister receiver, can i get list of registered receviers?

Comment: Which adapter are you using for inflating Fragments in the ViewPager ?

Comment: I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, on getItemMethod i am creating fragments like Document.newInstance(); by position

Comment: I've posted an answer below. Please do have a look. If you still have any queries, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register and unregister Broadcast Receivers in the ViewPager's `OnPageChangeListener`. This listener contains 3 methods namely `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)`, `onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels)` and `onPageSelected(int position)`.

Use `onPageScrolledStateChanged()` method. It uses 3 states for monitoring the Fragments inside the ViewPager. Use `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` for unregistering your BroadcastReceiver and `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` for registering your BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use setUserVisibleHint() method in your fragment... Or another idea, register OnPageChangeListener on your view pager and from this listener you can manualy call method for unregister your reciever...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers, as you said i implemented `OnPageChangeListener` and created a logic, it is working fine now. Thank you all again, i am posting the code:

```
   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {

       Fragment currentFragment = adapterViewPager.getRegisteredFragment(position);

       if(currentFragment.getClass()==Document.class){
           Log.i (AppConfig.TAG,"Current Fragment is Document");
           Document document = (Document)currentFragment;
           document.registerDownloadService();
       }
       if(lastFragment!=null && lastFragment.getClass()==Document.class){
           Log.i (AppConfig.TAG,"Previous Fragment is Document");
           Document document = (Document)lastFragment;
           document.unregisterDownloadService();
       }
       lastFragment = currentFragment;
   }
```